# How to map page.locator to $ in playwright using a fixture

Tags: playwright, fixtures

I want to map the page.locator to a simpler "$" much like the query in the past.
But when I try to make it with a fixture it fails with the error.

```
$: [async ({ page }, use) => {
  const $ = page.locator;
 
  await use($);
}, { scope: 'worker' }]
```

The error is: worker fixture "$" cannot depend on a test fixture "page" defined in ../../node_modules/playwright/lib/index.js:918:39.

Comment: What about this: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-query-selector ?

Comment: @Infern0 I think OP wants the `$` to map to `.locator`, so they get the benefits of locators, like auto-await. `page.$` doesn't wait and is discouraged, as the link shows.